# Intersection of line and circle to evaluate integral

Tags: calculus

I have to evaluate $\int \int_{D}^{}x^2+y^2-1dA$ over $D = \left \{(x,y) \in R^2: 0\leq x \leq y,x^2+y^2\leq 1 \right \}$

My problem is defining the integral limits for $x$ and $y$.

I believe that the reagion is the intersection of the circle with the line. Doing that, I got

$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}}\int_{0}^{1}x^2+y^2-1dydx$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Do you have to use rectangular coordinates?

Comment: @ZettaSuro Nops. I've just realized that is better to use polar coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a sketch. If you *really* want to use rectangular coordinates, then $y$ will go from $x$ to $\sqrt{1-x^2}$. The integration is quite feasible.

The natural thing to do, however, is to switch to polar coordinates. So $dx\,dy$ becomes $r\,dr\,d\theta$, and you are integrating from $r=0$ to $r=1$, and $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: How did you came up with that value (sorry but I really don't understand)? May I assume that the values of $x$ are correct?

Comment: I drew a picture. The region $D$ is the first-quadrant region **above** the line $y=x$, and inside the circle. So for any $x$, the smallest $y$ is $x$, and the largest $y$ is limited by the top half of the circle.  And yes, $x$ travels from $0$ to $1/\sqrt{2}$, that part was right.

Comment: Thanks. Before asking this question I've also have drawn a picture but did not get to that result. Still don't understand. Sorry but my calculus is very bad.

Comment: You were right. I now got to polar coordinates and I believe that it is more simple. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do as follows:

$$\left(\int_0^{\sqrt{2}/2}\int_0^y+\int_{\sqrt{2}/2}^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\right) f(x,y)dy~dx$$

[image]