# Converting to polar coordinates

Tags: calculus

I have to evaluate $\int \int_{D}^{}8-(2x^2+2y^2)dA$ over $D = \left \{(x,y) \in R^2: y\geq |x|,x^2+y^2\leq 4 \right \}$

Following another question I've posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415659/intersection-of-line-and-circle-to-evaluate-integral), I was advised to use polar coordinates.

I can see that one integral will be from $0$ to $2$. This is my $r$. The problem is finding $\theta$.

For $\theta$ I'm finding the intersection between the line and the circle. For that this is what I've done;
$$y=|x|$$
$$x^2+|x|^2=4 \Rightarrow 2x^2=4 \Rightarrow x^2=2 \Rightarrow x = \pm\sqrt{2}$$
Plugging that into $y$ I got that the points of intersection are $(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$  and $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$

I don't know if this is correct or not.

So this is my question. How can I convert those points to polar coordinates so I can plug in
$$\int_{\theta}^{\theta}\int_{0}^{2}8-(2(rcos(\theta))^2+2(rsin(\theta))^2)rdrd\theta $$

Comment: The two points of intersection you found are correct. Note that the point $(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$ lies at an angle of $-\frac{5 \pi}{4}$ to the $x$-axis and $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$ at an angle of $\frac{\pi}{4}$ so the limits of integration for $\theta$ 
should be $-\frac{5\pi}{4} \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$.
It is a good idea to sketch the area you are looking at. In this case it looks like a pacman tilted 90 degrees anti clockwise. This means your integral will be $$\int\limits_{-\frac{5\pi}{4} }^{\frac{\pi}{4} }\int\limits_{0}^{2}8-(2(rcos(\theta))^2+2(rsin(\theta))^2)rdrd\theta$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limits you needed according to $D$ is as follows:

$$\theta|_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2},~~r|_0^2$$ So we need to evaluate $$2\int_{\theta}\int_{r}f(r,\theta)r~drd\theta$$

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks but I made a mistake. its $y\geq|x|$ but I understood the point

Comment: @Favolas: Did you change the assumptions? If so I can make the answer accordingly. Do you want me to do again? :-)

Comment: Yes please. I now believe that $\theta$ should go from $\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ but I don't know if I'm correct :(

Comment: @Favolas: You are correct.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I was struggling to understand where the $\frac{\pi}{2}$ came from but figure it out that since they are symmetric you are multiplying the integral by 2

Comment: @Favolas: yes that is right. Welcome my friend

Comment: You're an image-making machine! ;-) +1

Comment: @amWhy: Through teaching, I have found out that plotting or making an image is one of the best way to propose a mathematical approach especially in Calculus. Even in analysis, even in Gorup theory!!

Comment: @Babak I agree!